# Updating multiple input values using one submit button in a loop

Tags: php, arrays, forms, loops

**I have** an array stored inside a session. I have echoed out each key and value using a foreach loop. Next to each key there is an input box for updating the value for that specific key.

**The problem** is that, each input box has its own submit button for updating the value. I want to make it only one submit that updates all input boxes.

**I tried** placing the submit button and the  outside of the loop. But that only updates the last value in the loop and not any other one.
I tried having it even outside the php and rewriting it as html, but it still didnt work for some reason.

THANKS in advance!

```
MY CODE!
    <?php
// begin the session
session_start();

// create an array
$my_array=array('cat', 'dog', 'mouse');

// put the array in a session variable
if(!isset($_SESSION['animals']))
    $_SESSION['animals']=$my_array;

// move submit code outside of foreach loop
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) 
{
    $aaa = $_POST['aaa'];
    $key_var = $_POST['ke'];

    // setting the session spesific session array value different for each key  
    $_SESSION['animals'][$key_var] = $aaa;
}

// loop through the session array with foreach
foreach($_SESSION['animals'] as $key=>$value)
{   

    // and print out the values
    echo 'The value of key ' .$key. ' is '."'".$value."'".' <br />';
    echo "update the value of key " .$key. " in the input box bellow";

    // getting the updated value from input box
    ?>
    <form method="post" action="">
        <input type="text" name="aaa" value="<?php echo $value ; ?>" size="2" />
        <!-- take a hidden input with value of key -->
        <input type="hidden" name="ke" value="<?php echo $key; ?>">

        <input type="submit" value="Update value of key" name="submit"/></div>
    </form>
    <?php
}


?>
```

**UPDATE** 
So I used Vijaya Sankar N's code and Audite Marlow' code and they both work perfectly.

**Updated code by Audite Marlow**

```
<?php
// begin the session
session_start();

// create an array
$my_array=array('cat', 'dog', 'mouse');

// put the array in a session variable
if(!isset($_SESSION['animals']))
    $_SESSION['animals']=$my_array;

// move submit code outside of foreach loop
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) 
{
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['aaa']); $i++) {
    $aaa = $_POST['aaa'][$i];
    $key_var = $_POST['ke'][$i];

    // setting the session spesific session array value different for each     key  
    $_SESSION['animals'][$key_var] = $aaa;
}
}
?>
<form method="post" action="">
<?php
// loop through the session array with foreach
foreach($_SESSION['animals'] as $key=>$value)
{   

    // and print out the values
    echo 'The value of key ' .$key. ' is '."'".$value."'".' <br />';
    echo "update the value of key " .$key. " in the input box bellow";

    // getting the updated value from input box
    ?>
        <input type="text" name="aaa[]" value="<?php echo $value ; ?>"    size="2" />
        <!-- take a hidden input with value of key -->
        <input type="hidden" name="ke[]" value="<?php echo $key; ?>">

    <?php
 }
 ?>

 <input type="submit" value="Update value of key" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: putting the <form> before the loop gives me an error  Undefined index: aaa and  Undefined index: ke. and it doesnt update antying :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the form around your foreach loop. Put the submit button outside of your foreach loop, inside your form. Inside the foreach loop, make the names of your inputs an array, like so:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <?php
    // loop through the session array with foreach
    foreach($_SESSION['animals'] as $key=>$value)
    {   

        // and print out the values
        echo 'The value of key ' .$key. ' is '."'".$value."'".' <br />';
        echo "update the value of key " .$key. " in the input box bellow";

        // getting the updated value from input box
        ?>
            <input type="text" name="aaa[]" value="<?php echo $value ; ?>" size="2" />
            <!-- take a hidden input with value of key -->
            <input type="hidden" name="ke[]" value="<?php echo $key; ?>">

        <?php
    }
    ?>
    <input type="submit" value="Update value of key" name="submit"/></div>
</form>
```

Now, in your `isset($_POST['submit']) { ... }`, you want to loop through your input arrays like so:

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) 
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['aaa']); $i++) {
        $aaa = $_POST['aaa'][$i];
        $key_var = $_POST['ke'][$i];

        // setting the session spesific session array value different for each key  
        $_SESSION['animals'][$key_var] = $aaa;
    }
}
```

This way, you'll update all `$_SESSION['animals']` keys for every input.

Comment: YES! Thanks everyone for helping. But this is the code that worked. Audite Marlowked Thanks

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help. I have updated the code that works :)

Answer (score 0):

Move the form and button outside the foreach and generate text fields with the key as identifier.

```
<form method="post" action="">
<?php
foreach($_SESSION['animals'] as $key=>$value)
{  
    echo 'The value of key ' .$key. ' is '."'".$value."'";
    echo "update the value of key " .$key. " in the input box bellow <br />";
    echo "<input type='text' name='$key' value='$value' size='2' /> <br />";
}
?>
<input type="submit" value="Update value of key" name="submit"/></div>
</form>
```

and your PHP submit code will be as simple as:

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
    $_SESSION['animals'][$key] = $value;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response but there is an extra input box with this code and i get an error when i update saying this Undefined index: aaa   Undefined index: ke

Comment: look at the name, it is updated with the key, so you cannot call with aaa or ke, you can call with the $key

Comment: Vijaya Sankar N--- this code is also perfect! very simply explained thanks so much !

Comment: Glad that I helped you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't the position of the buttons, but the form and /form tags
When you click a button that is insiede a form /form block, the browser send all the data INSIDE the block.

If you want to update ALL the elements with one button, you have to open the form tag before the "foreach" block and close the /form tag outside the foreach block

Answer (score 0):

Just put everything in one form with one submit button. Than you need to make the input name unique, cause else only the last value will be submitted. I did this by creating an 'animal' input array. In your PHP you can just simply loop through the POST data.
Try this:

```
<?php
// begin the session
session_start();

// create an array
$my_array=array('cat', 'dog', 'mouse');

// put the array in a session variable
if(!isset($_SESSION['animals']))
    $_SESSION['animals']=$my_array;

// move submit code outside of foreach loop
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) 
{
    //Your new PHP to update all values
    if(isset($_POST['animal']) && count($_POST['animal']) > 0)
    {
        foreach($_POST['animal'] as $key => $value)
        {
            $_SESSION['animals'][$key] = $value;
        }
    }
}

?>

<form method="post" action="">

<?php

    // loop through the session array with foreach
    foreach($_SESSION['animals'] as $key=>$value)
    {   

        // and print out the values
        echo 'The value of key ' .$key. ' is '."'".$value."'".' <br />';
        echo "update the value of key " .$key. " in the input box bellow";

        // getting the updated value from input box
        ?>

            <input type="text" name="animal[<?= $key ?>]" value="<?= $value ?>" size="2" />
        <?php
    }


?>
<input type="submit" value="Update all values" name="submit"/></div>
</form>
```